# Interpretation of Hilbert/Frobenius series shift

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions, frobenius-schur-indicator

Let $V = \oplus_{i\geq 0} V^i$ be a graded vector space.
Recall that the Hilbert series is defined as

$$F(q) = \sum_{i\geq 0} q^i \operatorname{dim}(V^i),$$

or if we have a graded $S_n$-module, $M$, we can decompose each homogeneous part into irreducible representations and compute the Frobenius series as

$$\Phi(x;q) = \sum_{i\geq 0} q^i \sum_\lambda \operatorname{mult}(S^\lambda,M^i)s_\lambda(x),$$
where $s_\lambda(x)$ is the Schur function.

Now, given such $M$, is there a natural interpretation of $\Phi(x;q+1)$?
That is, can we construct some new $S_n$-module / representation with
Frobenius series $\Phi(x;q+1)$?

**Possible construction?**

Suppose $V^d = \operatorname{span}\{m_{1}(x_1,\dotsc,x_n),\dotsc,m_k(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)\}$ where the $m_j$ are homogeneous polynomials in say $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ of degree $d$, and $S_n$ act by permuting the indices of the variables.

So how do we construct $(1+q)^i$?
Express each monomial in $m_i$ as a product, $x_{j_1} x_{j_2} \dotsm x_{j_d}$
with indices ordered increasingly. Consider this as a *non-commutative* monomial, and consider all possible substitutions $x_t \to y_t$ (but the $t$th entry is then replaced in all the $m_i$ simultaneously).
This gives $2^d$ *non-commutative polynomials*, each of which "looks" like $V^d$, but with a subset of the indices replaced by $y$.

The new $S_n$-action act on permuting the indices, (on both $x$ and $y$),
but the degree of a copy of $V^i$ is the $x$-variable-degree.
Here, *after* we have constructed the copies, one should consider the polynomials commutative again, in order for $S_n$ to preserve the $V^i$-copy.

So, the idea is some non-commutative lifting, which allow us to create graded copies of the $V^i$. **Does this make any sense?**

Comment: I am not sure if the frobenius-schur-indicator tag is appropriate (it sounds like this is what I want).